# How to use raw datatype DOUBLE(x, y) on Yii2 Migration

Tags: mysql, database, yii2, migration

I use Yii2 DB Migration tool to make a double(17,3) column on my table

```
$this->createTable('{{%temp_transaction}}', [
    'balance' => 'double(17,3) NOT NULL',  // <-- will be DOUBLE() with no length
```

But I can do the alter using raw query on my DB directly

```sql
ALTER TABLE `temp_transaction` CHANGE `balance` `balance` DOUBLE(17,3)  NOT NULL;
```

Is it a bug from Yii2 or I need to use other workaround? Thank you.

Comment: When `yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder` converts abstract column types into dbms specific column types it pretty much removes any precision set for `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` types. That's probably because setting precision as `DOUBLE(x, y)` is deprecated in MySQL and there are actually only two different precision for floating point types represented by `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`. If you need fixed length after decimal point you might want to use fixed point type like `DECIMAL` instead.

Comment: Why don't use existing method `$this->double()`? It's allows to specify precision

Comment: @SiZE even if that method allows you to specify precision in the end for MySQL the precision is still ignored.

Comment: @MichalHynčica btw its not a good idea using float (double) for money :) Use DECIMAL.